# How to group subtotals on the same row by date, by code

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, subtotal

I couldn't find an equivalent question on here for this question.  Apologies if this is a repeat
Basically I have a table with transactions.  Each transaction has a code and a datetime stamp.  I want to be able to create a SQL query so that the results look something like this

```
+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
|    DATE    | CODE1  | COUNT1 | CODE2 | COUNT2 | CODE3 | COUNT3 |
+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
| 2017-01-01 | George |     12 | John  |     10 | Ringo |    114 |
+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
```

I currently have a query that I can pull the subtotals on individual lines, i.e:

```
SELECT CONVERT(mytime AS DATE), code, COUNT(*) FROM transactiontable
GROUP BY CONVERT(mytime AS DATE), code
ORDER BY CONVERT(mytime AS DATE), code
```

Would give me

```
DATE             CODE       COUNT
-----------------------------------
2017-01-01       George      12
2017-01-01        John       10
```

etc ...

I don't currently have a separate table for the codes, but I am considering it.

Thanks !

Comment: Is there an upper limit to number of code/count columns?

Comment: Good question.  it's under 100, probably about 50.

Comment: Isn't CONVERT function datatype argument first e.g. CONVERT(DATE, mytime)?

Comment: Someone suggested pivoting ... I think that will work. Looks like that comment went away though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can use `PIVOT` for making this.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DATE DATETIME,  CODE  VARCHAR(10), [COUNT] INT)
INSERT INTO @Table

VALUES
('2017-01-01','George',12),
('2017-01-01','John',10)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE), * FROM @Table
)
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT DATE, CONCAT('CODE',RN) RN, CODE Value FROM CTE
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT DATE, CONCAT('COUNT',RN) RN,  CONVERT(VARCHAR,[COUNT]) Value FROM CTE
        ) SRC
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR RN IN ([CODE1],[COUNT1],[CODE2],[COUNT2])) PVT
```

Result:

```
DATE        CODE1       COUNT1      CODE2    COUNT2 
----------- ----------- ----------- -------- -------
2017-01-01  George      12          John     10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function row_number to form groups and use conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select dt,
    max(case when rn = 1 then code end) as code_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then cnt end) as code_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then code end) as code_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then cnt end) as code_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then code end) as code_3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then cnt end) as code_3,
    ....
from (
    select convert(date, mytime) as dt, 
        code, 
        count(*),
        row_number() over (partition by convert(date, mytime) order by code) as rn
    from transactiontable
    group by convert(date, mytime), code
    ) t
group by dt
order by dt;
```